# remove specified ttl in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I read about updating ttl and that it is only possible by updating row.
But I want to remove ttl. I fear it is the same process, but I did not found any information about it. Is there a way to remove ttl without updating all rows?

What I do, is saving user information with ttl when user is registrating. So if the user do not validate his/her mail address the entry will automaticly delete.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt from the official docs [**here**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html).

> If you want to change the TTL of expiring data, you have to re-insert
>   the data with a new TTL. In Cassandra, the insertion of data is
>   actually an insertion or update operation, depending on whether or not
>   a previous version of the data exists.
>
> TTL data has a precision of one second, as calculated on the server.
>   Therefore, a very small TTL probably does not make much sense.
>   Moreover, the clocks on the servers should be synchronized; otherwise
>   reduced precision could be observed because the expiration time is
>   computed on the primary host that receives the initial insertion but
>   is then interpreted by other hosts on the cluster.

This is slightly unpleasant in practice, but it's relatively easy to build a very simple migration tool, you would simply iterate through the entire table and re-insert all the records with a new TTL in another table.

If computationally/storage-wise you can afford to do this, it's probably a more compelling idea to store the records twice, once with TTL and once without, simply to go around the limitation: you cannot cancel or change the TTL in Cassandra.